# Connect to "Azure Database for MySQL-Server" from Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, azure, ubuntu-20.04, azure-mysql-database

I'm trying to connect from a Ubuntu 20.04 Server to an Azure Database for MySQL-Server from terminal. That worked fine until two days ago.
When i hit enter now the mysql warning is displayed and nothing happens:

```
user@ubuntu2004:~$ mysql -uuser -ppassword -hmyserver.mysql.database.azure.com

mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
```

MySQL Server Version Ubuntu Server: Ver 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

Azure MySQL Server Version: 8.0.15

However, i can connect to the remote database from Mac.

MySQL Version on Mac:
Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.32, for osx10.12 (x86_64)

Does anyone have an idea why it works on Mac and on ubuntu not?

Comment: if that where your ral  credentials change them urgently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem happens to me.

Azure Database for MySQL has some touble for 8.0.27 mysql client.

Downgrade it to 8.0.19.

```
# apt remove mysql-client-8.0 mysql-client-core-8.0
# apt install mysql-client-8.0=8.0.19* mysql-client-core-8.0=8.0.19*
```